# Is it possible to use the same network socket simultaneously for listen and connect with the same port?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port

I want to use **socket** to implement that the **client/server** can **send and receive** the files from each other. The client can send and receive the files from the server and vice versa for the server. Also, need to use the **Tkinter** module to complete the server and client GUI.

When the 2 GUIs are initialed, a thread is started to listen to the connection from the opposite end. That means the server has a thread for listening and accepting the connection from the client while receiving the file from the client, and at the client-side, the thread is used to listen and accept the connection from the server.

My confusion is that whether do I need 2 ports, one is used for **sending** file from the client to the server, another one is to **receiving** the files from the server? And do I need to create 2 sockets for sending and receiving files?

My current solution is using **2 ports** and **2 sockets** in the client-side. when sending the file, the client-side acts the client, while receiving file it acts the server. Correct?

**To be brief, is it possible to use the same network socket simultaneously for `listen` and `connect to` with the same port? Or must I have two separate sockets, and if so, must the separate sockets also be bound to separate network ports?**

Here is a simplified code that explains my questions. Any advice/comments are appreciated. Thanks.

```
class client():
    def __init__(self):
        self.clientTcpSock = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #create UI here

    def createSocket(self):
        s.clientTcpSock = socket()
        s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((HOST, PORT_1)) #PORT_1 download file port
        s.listen(5)
        self.clientTcpSock = s

    def sendFile(self):
        # !!! Here creates a new TCP socket, or can i still use the same clientTcpSock??

        s = socket()
        s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.connect((HOST, PORT_2))  # PORT_2 upload file port
        s.send(b'hello world') # just for example


    def receiveFile(self):

        while True:
            ### receivefile here

        self.clientTcpSock.close()


    # call this function when init UI
    def newTherad(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receiveFile, args=())
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
```

Comment: I think there's some confusion about terms here. A "server" is a process that listens for and accepts connections; a "client" is something that makes connections to a server. So you have two servers here, each acting as a client of the other. That raises a question. Sockets are _bidirectional_; I can send data from either end and receive it on the other. So your code would probably be simplified if you picked *one* of the applications and made it the server, and then transferred data as needed.

Comment: But a short answer to your question is, no, you cannot listen on a socket and then later call `connect` or `send` on it. You will get an `OSError`.

Comment: Thanks @bnaecker. Yes, here 2 servers, each acts as a client of the other.  But may I use the same port for 2 different sockets, one socket is for listening and another for connecting here? And how about the FTP process, the client-side can upload and download the files to(from) the server?  I only know there're 2 ports, one for control and another for data.

Comment: Two processes _on the same machine_ cannot use the same port for TCP sockets. If these programs are on separate machines, then sure, you can use the same port number. You don't mention FTP anywhere in your question, but if this is really an FTP system, consider using Python's builtin [`ftplib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html).

Comment: Yes, I did not mention FTP in the question, but I feel my application function sending and receiving files like what the FTP does. OK, I will consider using the `ftplib` module. thanks